# 403 forbidden error on api url

Tags: express, http-status-code-403

I'm using express.js to submit a search query for [this](http://food2fork.com/about/api) api. A json object is returned. It contains an image url pointing to the api's website. When trying to get the image, 403 forbidden is returned.

Here's an example [url](http://static.food2fork.com/cajun0676.jpg/). It shows an XML error with 'Access Denied' message. Perhaps I somehow need to include my api key in the url to get access? If so, how can I do that?

Here's my code:

```
var str = '';
var ingredients = null;
router.post('/', function(req,res){

 ingredients = req.body.ingredients; //get value of an <input> named 'ingredients'
 var callback = function(response){
 str = '';

 //another chunk of data has been recieved, so append it to `str`
 response.on('data', function (chunk) {
   str += chunk;
 });

 //the whole response has been recieved
 response.on('end', function () {
  var recipes = JSON.parse(str); //parse string to json
  res.render('home', {recipes: recipes}); //render view with required object
 });
}

var options = {
 host: "food2fork.com",
 path: "/api/search?key=[myKey]&q=" + ingredients
};

if(ingredients != null)
{
 http.request(options,callback).end();
 ingredients = null;
}

});
```

Used code form [nodejitsu](https://docs.nodejitsu.com/articles/HTTP/clients/how-to-create-a-HTTP-request).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out I was mistyping an HTML handlebars image element:

```
<img src={{image_url}}/>
```

Instead of

```
<img src={{image_url}} />
```

which added an extra "/" at the end of the url and caused the issue.